# Python: Replace index element of array in text file on each line

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks similar to:

```
20, 32, 28, 32

27, 38, 30, 30

82, 39, 28, 18

29, 38, 10, 20

90, 28, 29, 09
```

If the value in the first column is > 50 then the remaining data is replaced with 0.

So it should look like this:

```
20, 32, 28, 32

27, 38, 30, 30

82, 0, 0, 0

29, 38, 10, 20

90, 0, 0, 0
```

I am really stuck on how to go about this. I have searched this site, but only find examples with one list e.g. `a=[20,32,28,32]`. but I have 5 different rows (is each row a separate list?)

Any help would her very much welcomed.

Comment: Doing this with pure python is going to be painstaking. Do you have numpy or pandas?

Comment: should the result be written to the new file?

Comment: II have never come across numpy before. No the result does not have to be written to the new file as I will be doing additional calculations once the '0' have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [for](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) loop and do for each row what you'd do for one row.

Here's an example:

```
with open("example_file", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # do what you'd do with one line
        new_line = [int(l) for l in line.split(',')]
        if new_line[0] > 50:
            new_line[1:] = [0]*(len(new_line)-1)
        # process the line further ... save it to another file?
```

Comment: You are amazing! That is just what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this. COde need to be changed if number of columns changes

```
fle =open("C:\Python27\projects\infile.txt")
lst=fle.readlines()
lst=[i.strip() for i in lst]

for i in lst:
        j=i.split(',')
        if int(j[0]) > 50:

                for k in range(1,len(j)):
                    j[k]=0

        print ','.join(str(l) for l in j)
fle.close()
```

Comment: Are you seriously going to sit and individually set each element to 0? what if you have 10,000 columns? Will you repeat this 10,000 times?

Answer (score 0):

What you have found for a single list can also be used as multiple lists. Let's have a `data.txt` which contains out data like below:

`data.txt`

```
20, 32, 28, 32

27, 38, 30, 30

82, 39, 28, 18

29, 38, 10, 20

90, 28, 29, 09
```

Now we are going to read the data and process those as required. Finally we will write the processed data in a new file called `output_data.txt`. The program can be solved in the following way:

```
output_lines = []
with open("data.txt", "r") as input_file:
    input_lines = input_file.readlines()
    for line in input_lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line!="":
            ar = list(map(int, line.split(",")))
            if ar[0] > 50:
                ar[1:] = [0] * (len(ar)-1)
            output_lines.append(", ".join([str(i) for i in ar]))
with open("output_data.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for line in output_lines:
        output_file.write(line+"\n")
```

`output_data.txt` contains:

```
20, 32, 28, 32
27, 38, 30, 30
82, 0, 0, 0
29, 38, 10, 20
90, 0, 0, 0
```

There are many alternatives to solve this. I have showed the most trivial one.